# PHP redirection/popup: Keep existing page and pop up a new tab

Tags: php, redirect

I read that we can use the following in the meta tags for redirection to another page after desired number of minutes:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; url=http://www.example.com/" />
```

That is fine if it's acceptable to navigate away from the page that user is on. But what I am trying to do is that instead of navigating to another page, I want to pop up a new browser tab/window and also have the existing page as it is. I would like to do this strictly **without Javascript**.

So consider an example. Say user arrives on 1.php page. Now user will have 10 minutes to read the information on this page. At the end of 10 minutes, I want to pop up a new tab/window which points to the page 2.php and shows the information contained in it. So after the 10 minute, I will have 1.php page as it is and a new tab/window that shows 2.php page. I don't want to disturb the user for whatever he is doing on 1.php and hence want to just pop-up 2.php page.

How can I achieve this **without** using javascript/ajax?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT1:**

If there is no way to do achieve this in PHP, how can I achieve this via Javascript? I would want to launch a popup/popunder to 2.php to be able to achieve this functionality and keep the user on the same page as he was on.

Thanks.

Comment: A popup window (rather than a new tab) *will* disturb the user if they're still reading page 1.

Comment: You can't, and *no one* wants you too. It will only get your website blacklisted for unwanted pop-ups.

Comment: @JYelton I understand & agree with that. But it is ton times better if user is filling up a lengthy form on 1.php, pauses in between, tries to resume, only to find that is redirected. And this going to be the case in my application. Pop up may visibly disturb the user but I can write more information in the pop-up as to why they are getting to see it. So educating them that way, would surely simply complex matters to a large extent, I think.

Comment: @animuson The popup is meant to keep the user's session alive without using JS. Not to offend them with ads. Makes sense?

Comment: @Devner: Whatever your intention is, it's still an unwanted pop-up, and creating a pop-up is not an efficient way of extending sessions. If your form is that long, you should be splitting it up into pieces and storing each piece one at a time, or encouraging them to type it in an external application such as Notepad, then copying and pasting it to your form.

Comment: @animuson Although, what you said makes sense, in some cases having a big form (not too lengthy is required). It's even possible that maybe the user received a phone call and got busy and returned to fill up the half-filled form. That's just an example. So how can I achieve the popup/popunder functionality with JS?

Comment: An even better idea is to run an AJAX function that calls a script which simply extends the session and then does nothing. Eliminating the pop-up is worth AJAX.

Comment: Or use a hidden iframe that refers to a php page that accesses $_SESSION vars (to keep the session alive) and has auto refresh (via <meta>). That wouldn't require javascript. In any case, you probably should update your original question as to the purpose (wanting to keep the session alive) as it is not apparent as is. Doing so would probably net you better and more applicable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is extending the user session (based on you comments), a javascript-less way might be to create a hidden <iframe> that refers to a page that auto-refreshes and keeps the session alive.

Ex, in your main page you'll have:

```
<iframe src="keepalive.php" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px"></iframe>
```

an in keepalive.php you'll have:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['i_am_alive'] = "something";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" />
    </head>
    <body>OK</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2:
Works in both Firefox and IE 8. Make sure to test in all browsers you need to support. You can include a <script>alert("something")</script> in keepalive.php during development just so you know it auto-refreshing. Do note that including the script snippet will prompt a warning in IE8 which should disappear when you remove the script part.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just increase your session max timeout in php.ini, or do periodic (and unnoticeable by the user) AJAX requests to the server to keep the session alive.

Users simply do not want obtrusive popups, especially if the user has no idea what the purpose of the popup is for.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I'm pretty sure you **cant** do it without JS you want to manipulate the browser, PHP can't handle that.

Comment: I find it interesting you chose to bold can't (first negation), but not without (second negation)